# After changing from gulp v3 to v4, gulp.series isn't running all tasks applied

Tags: gulp

After migration from gulp v3 to v4, i have to exchange the use of run-sequence plugin with the new methods provided by gulp v4 which are series and parallel. But i have found that not all the tasks is applied after this exchange.

I have followed tutorials to transform between run-sequence use and series and parallel methods provided by gulp 4, but as i said not all tasks is applied.

Here is the original gulpfile.js code with gulp v3:

```js
// Multi watch
gulp.task( "watchChanges" , function() { // tasks done before watch
    gulp.watch( sourceFolder + "/scss/**/*.scss" , ["sass"] ); // src , task name
    gulp.watch( sourceFolder + "/*.html" , browserSync.reload ); // watch html (src)
    gulp.watch( sourceFolder + "/js/**/*.js" , browserSync.reload ); // watch js (src)
});

gulp.task( "default" , function( callback ) {
    runSequence( [ "sass" , "browserSync" ] , "watchChanges" ,
        callback
    )
});
```

And here is the code transform i have applied for gulp v4:

```js
// Multi watch
gulp.task( "watchChanges" , function() { // tasks done before watch
    gulp.watch( sourceFolder + "/scss/**/*.scss" , gulp.series( "sass" ) ); // src , task name  
    gulp.watch( sourceFolder + "/*.html" ).on( "change" , browserSync.reload ); // watch html (src)
    gulp.watch( sourceFolder + "/js/**/*.js" ).on( "change" , browserSync.reload ); // watch js (src)
});

// default task
gulp.task( "default" , gulp.series( gulp.parallel( "sass" , "browserSync" ) , "watchChanges" ) );
```

And for the usage of `sass` and `browserSync` are as following:

```js
// sass task
gulp.task( "sass" , function() {
    return gulp.src( sourceFolder + "/scss/**/*.scss" ) // source
        .pipe( sourcemaps.init() ) // sourcemaps init
        .pipe( sass({ outputStyle: "compressed" }).on( "error" , sass.logError ) ) // define plugin
        .pipe( sourcemaps.write("./sourcemaps") ) // sourcemaps write
        .pipe( gulp.dest( sourceFolder + "/css" ) ) // destination
        .pipe( browserSync.stream() ); // injecting css in browser
});

// browserSync task
gulp.task( "browserSync" , function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: sourceFolder
        }
    });
});
```

For the use of gulp v3, the tasks run normally in a sequence of **sass** - **browserSync** - **watchChanges**, but after making the change with gulp v4, just **sass** and **browserSync** run but for **watchChanges** it doesn't run!

but if i tried `gulp sass browserSync watchChanges`, all these tasks will run correctly!

I hope if i have an explanation and a solution of why this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
// browserSync task
gulp.task( "browserSync" , function(done) {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: sourceFolder
        }
    });
    done();
});
```

Because you did not signal the completion of the `browserSync` task, gulp is unable to know to move on the next task.  The `done` in the above code does that.